# how to receive formatted numbers inputs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

in python how to read input numbers in formats like:
1,000,000
1,000.25
20%
20 %

i want my code to understand if user put
1,000,000 equal 1000000
1,000.25 equal 1000.25

and if user put 25 = 25% = 25 % all equal to 0.25

```
clname=input("Enter Your Nanem: ")
clloan=float(input("Enter your loan value: "))
clrate=float(input("enter your loan rate - format 0.000 : "))
clyears=float(input("enter loan period in years: "))

rtval=clloan * clrate * clyears
total=clloan + rtval
monthlypayment=total / (clyears * 12)
print("**************************************************")
print("Client: ", clname)
print("a loan of: ",clloan , " ,at rate: ",clrate , " ,on period: " ,clyears," years")
print("rate value is: ", rtval)
print("total payment will be: ",total)
print("and your monthly payment will be: ",monthlypayment)
```

result:

```
Enter Your Nanem: mm
Enter your loan value: 1,000,000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\pythonProjects\test1\VID4_exercise.py", line 22, in <module>
    clloan=float(input("Enter your loan value: "))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,000,000'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `clloan.replace(",",")` and `clrate.replace("%","")`?

Comment: There's no automatic parsing for this.  You have to do it yourself.  It's not difficult.  `if '%' in value:` / `value = float(value.replace('%',''))/100`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace()` to replace the "," and "%" before converting them to float.

```
clloan=float(input("Enter your loan value: ").replace(",",""))
clrate=float(input("enter your loan rate - format 0.000 : ").replace("%",""))
```

If you are worried about extra space you can use `replace(" ","")`. You can divide the percentage value by 100 as well if you want decimal point values.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a different approach.

Rather than replacing characters (e.g., comma, percent) consider extracting only those characters that might possibly makes sense. Then try to convert to float.

Something like this:

```
NUMS = set('0123456789.-+')

def myFloat(s):
    sn = ''.join(c for c in s if c in NUMS)
    # there is potential for ValueError here if input string makes no sense or is empty
    rv = float(sn)
    return rv / 100 if s[-1] == '%' else rv

for value in '1,000,000', '-12.5', '15%':
    print(value, myFloat(value))
```

**Output:**

```
1,000,000 1000000.0
-12.5 -12.5
15% 0.15
```

Comment: i didn't understand these parts: 1-[ sn = ''.join ] sn = '' what '' represent here , 2- [ s[-1] ] you used s as an array but why position -1 should return the %  , and what if user entered "5 %" with space will it still be valid ?

Comment: @MoMo You can access individual characters of a string through indexing. Providing the string is not empty then an index of -1 refers to the last character in the string. In the code shown in my answer, only characters in the NUMS set are allowed. Therefore any spaces in the input will be ignored

Comment: but % is not allowed in the set, how could it be found ?

Comment: @MoMo The code checks the last character in the original string (*s*) for '%'. It does not test the string constructed from the set (*sn*)

Answer (score 0):

thank you from your answers i get the idea

i used contains and replace to fix the input numbers and here is the last solution:

```
clname=input("Enter Your Name: ")

clloan=input("Enter your loan value: ")
clloan= float(clloan.replace('$','').replace(',','').replace(' ',''))

clrate=input("enter your loan rate : ")
clrate = float(clrate.replace('%','').replace(',','').replace(' ',''))
if clrate > 1:
    clrate = clrate / 100

clyears=float(input("enter loan period in years: "))

rtval=clloan * clrate * clyears
total=clloan + rtval
monthlypayment=total / (clyears * 12)
print("**************************************************")
print("Client: ", clname)
print("a loan of: ",clloan , " ,at rate: ",clrate , " ,on period: " ,clyears," years")
print("rate value is: ", rtval)
print("total payment will be: ",total)
print("and your monthly payment will be: ",monthlypayment)
```

result:

```
Enter Your Name: mm
Enter your loan value: 1,000,000
enter your loan rate : 25
enter loan period in years: 5
**************************************************
Client:  mm
a loan of:  1000000.0  ,at rate:  0.25  ,on period:  5.0  years
rate value is:  1250000.0
total payment will be:  2250000.0
and your monthly payment will be:  37500.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thanks to @Tim roberts , i now shortened this code:

```
clloan=input("Enter your loan value: ")

if clloan.__contains__(","):
   clloan=clloan.replace(",", "")

if clloan.__contains__(","):
   clloan = clloan.replace(" ", "")

clloan = float(clloan)

clrate=input("enter your loan rate : ")
if clrate.__contains__("%"):
   clrate=clrate.replace("%", "")

if clrate.__contains__(" "):
   clrate=clrate.replace(" ", "")

clrate = float(clrate)

if clrate > 1:
   clrate = clrate / 100
```

Comment: Two comments.  First, don't use the `__contains__` special method.  Just do `if '%' in clrate:`.  Second, you don't need to check for the characters.  `replace` works even if the string is not present.  Just do the `replace`s.  You can chain them:  `clrate = clrate.replace('%','').replace(',','').replace(' ','')`.